# What language is used in this HTML that has double curly braces?

Tags: javascript, html

What language is used in this HTML code that has double curly braces? i.e. {{}} I think it's not JavaScript.

```
<script id="todo-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

            <li {{#if completed}}class="completed"{{/if}} data-id="{{id}}">
                <div class="view">
                    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" {{#if completed}}checked{{/if}}>
                    <button class="destroy"></button>
                </div>
                <input class="edit" value="{{title}}">
            </li>

        </script>
        <script id="footer-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <span class="todo-count"><strong>{{activeTodoCount}}</strong> {{activeTodoWord}} left</span>
            <ul class="filters">
                <li>
                    <a {{#eq filter 'all'}}class="selected"{{/eq}} href="#/all">All</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a {{#eq filter 'active'}}class="selected"{{/eq}}href="#/active">Active</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a {{#eq filter 'completed'}}class="selected"{{/eq}}href="#/completed">Completed</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{#if completedTodos}}<button class="clear-completed">Clear completed</button>{{/if}}
        </script>
        <script src="node_modules/todomvc-common/base.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/director/build/director.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The answer is in the code, you've `type="text/x-handlebars-template"`.

Comment: tell me the name of language

Comment: See https://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: it can be sort of a templating like in javascript!

Answer (score 1):

It's a templating language called Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com

Answer (score 1):

It's handlebars https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars/. Handlebars allows templates to be precompiled and included as javascript code rather than the handlebars template allowing for faster startup time